# How to set properties of JLabel in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, jlabel

I have 10 JLabels which are named label1, label2, label3, ... , label10. I want to set the text in the labels using a `for` loop. So what I want to be able to do is like the following:

Obviously this doesn't work.

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
    label+i.setText("label"+i);
}
```

Is there any way to actually be able to do this? I really need to do this so that I don't have to hard code everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store your JLabels in an array. That is:

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[10];
// Fill that array with your JLables
for (JLabel l : labels) {
  l.setText("label"+i);
}
```

And get rid of those label1, label2, label3, ... , label10 variables; they're not useful.

This type of loop is a for-each loop; `for (JLabel l : labels)` says "for each JLabel, `l`, of the array `labels`"; [documentation here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) *(Thanks Frakcool!)*

Comment: So how does this work? Could you please explain what the `:` does and what is this program doing?

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal that kind of `for-loop` is called a `"for-each"` loop: See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). The `:` means "on", so you could read the above example as: "for each JLabel l on labels"

Comment: @GKFX you're welcome; you should add my comment into your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to refer to a variable without knowing its exact name at compile time. The only option is using an array (or some other collection):

```
JLabel label0 = new JLabel();
JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
JLabel label5 = new JLabel();
JLabel label6 = new JLabel();
JLabel label7 = new JLabel();
JLabel label8 = new JLabel();
JLabel label9 = new JLabel();

JLabel[] label = new JLabel[] { label0, label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9 };
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    label[i].setText("label" + i);
}
```

To avoid typing so much (and possible typos), you might create labels in loop as well:

```
JLabel[] label = new JLabel[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    label[i] = new JLabel();
    label[i].setText("label" + i);
}
```

You can still refer to particular label using `label[4]` syntax. Notice the array is indexed from 0 so `label[0]` is the first element and `label[9]` is the 10th (last) element.

Comment: This looks good, but my question was a simplified version of what I am actually trying to do. I am trying to do `.setIcon`. So will your method still work? Also, since I will have 10 different `JLabels` on my `JFrame`, will I have to call `repaint()` and `reValidate()` inside the loop?

Comment: `setIcon` should work just like `setText`. If at all, you probably want to call `repaint()` and `revalidate()` on parent component (frame or panel). You can do this once - after you have finished changing all the labels.